# Разбить (партиционировать) CSV файл по столбцу

Tags: python, csv

Есть исходный CSV более 94000 строк. Нужно разбить этот файл на несколько отдельных CSV файлов. Критерий - это определенный бренд в столбце 5. Делаю так:

```py
import csv

with open('first.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=';')
    headers = reader.fieldnames
    print(headers[4])
#Get unique set of brands
    myset = set()
    for row in reader:
        myset.add(row[headers[4]])
        for brand in myset:
            filename = brand +".csv"
            with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as outfile:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=headers, extrasaction='ignore')
                if row[headers[4]] == brand:
                    writer.writeheader()
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

В итоге получаю несколько файлов по брендам и с нужными строками. Но из-за цикла получаю строки заголовком `header`.

Как вынести запись `header` только в начале файла?

Comment: самое простое, сделайте переменную, которую например обнуляйте перед цклом, и по нулю выводите хидер и делайте ее единичкой

Comment: Может через *pandas* делать? Из большого датафрейма делаете меньшие с использованием специальных запросов

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.

Comment: вы хотите вот эту строку ` writer.writeheader()` печатать один раз самой первой? `h=True; with open(filename, 'a', ...if row[headers[4]] == brand: if h : writer.writeheader();h= False`

Comment: Да, эту строку только вначале. Сейчас пытаюсь реализовать код из вашего комментария

Comment: @splash58, так будет работать только если CSV уже отсортирован. Иначе надо сделать словарь с именами брендов в качестве ключей и булевыми значениями в качестве значений

Comment: Поправил код поставив 'h = True' перед 'for row in reader:' Строка печатается только в первом файле в первой строке, в остальных файлах без первой строки совсем. При других расположениях результат как в исходном коде. Но проблема этого кода еще и в очень медленном выполнении. В pandas выполняется в секунды.

Comment: @Alex, `проблема этого кода еще и в очень медленном выполнении` - советую определиться - `"вам шашечки или ехать"`. Если нужна скорость и простота кода, то `Pandas` / `Numpy`, если только использование стандартных модулей и нет требований к скорости то `csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример исходного CSV файла:

```
ID,brand,val
1,aaa,57
2,bbb,58
3,ccc,33
4,aaa,5
5,ddd,55
6,aaa,84
7,bbb,17
8,ddd,38
9,ccc,5
10,aaa,86
11,ccc,69
12,ddd,83
```

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  conda install pandas | pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Temp\data.csv")

_ = df.groupby("brand").apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(fr"c:\temp\{x.name}.csv", index=False))
```

---

Результат:

**C:\Temp\aaa.csv**

```
ID,brand,val
1,aaa,57
4,aaa,5
6,aaa,84
10,aaa,86
```

**C:\Temp\bbb.csv**

```
ID,brand,val
2,bbb,58
7,bbb,17
```

**C:\Temp\ccc.csv**

```
ID,brand,val
3,ccc,33
9,ccc,5
11,ccc,69
```

**C:\Temp\ddd.csv**

```
ID,brand,val
5,ddd,55
8,ddd,38
12,ddd,83
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение с pandas. Принцип да такой, но хотелось бы иметь возможность выполнить задачу используя встроенный модуль csv. Не везде есть возможность установить pandas.

Comment: @Alex, лично мне скучно и лениво решать эту задачу с использованием модуля `csv`, но наверняка найдутся другие участники, которые помогут вам с этим...)

Comment: Ожидаю, что есть решение. В моем коде сделано почти) Только вывод такой, что после каждой строки с данными выводится каждый раз ID,brand,val.